# PHP получить загрузить файл переходя по ссылке

Tags: php, файлы, curl, get, save

ссылка по которой нужно перейти и получить файл -  https://91.cloudfone.vn/Home?ID=wqOQO11Wighi5IG%2FjZZDL3tJJKLTPZYc3k3hkVTBfvPvkPP1vUPUttMT9xdSkVvNNajI9KLcVSXIBZURYyuQFF6abfpsskbTPP2DcRotM%2BU%3D

При переходе в браузере файл начинает загружаться, пробовал через postman отправить get запрос в нем тоже загрузка произошла тело ответа сохранить в файлом получилось. Curl запрос созданный через postman запустил на сервере, пытался сохранить ответ, не сохраняет просто пустой файл, подскажите что не так, как сохранить полученный файл, это аудио файл wav 2 минуты

Пример curl из postman

```html
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://91.cloudfone.vn/Home?ID=wqOQO11Wighi5IG%2FjZZDL3tJJKLTPZYc3k3hkVTBfvPvkPP1vUPUttMT9xdSkVvNNajI9KLcVSXIBZURYyuQFF6abfpsskbTPP2DcRotM%2BU%3D",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/voice.wav',$response);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно в данном случае получить и сохранить файл на сервере?

Comment: https://91.cloudfone.vn/Home?ID=wqOQO11Wighi5IG%2FjZZDL3tJJKLTPZYc3k3hkVTBfvPvkPP1vUPUttMT9xdSkVvNNajI9KLcVSXIBZURYyuQFF6abfpsskbTPP2DcRotM%2BU%3D

Comment: Ссылку случайно не ту поставил, вот эта ссылка, в комментарии выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После вызова, у `$response` значение `false` - признак ошибки.

Причина (`echo curl_errno($curl);`) - SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (errno=60)

**Решения:** 1) установить локально сертификат, используемый запрашиваемым ресурсом. 2) отключить проверку сертификата: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло